# How to position a child widget that over the edge of the parent widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter and I am trying to overlap the child element on the parent element.

I tried using `Stack` but I have encountered widget overflow issue.

[image: layout sample]

Comment: It's totally doable with `Stack`, show what you've done so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this
https://pub.dev/packages/stack_overlay

If you don't want to use this extensions
Try using a fitted box, there is lots of documentation about that
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html